# android checkbox and check change listener

Tags: android, checkbox

in my android app i have a custom table list with one checkbox for each row.

i would like to check, if a checkbox was checked or unchecked.
for this i have this code:

```
SelectCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (SelectCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                            Log.e("-->", "IS CHECKED");
                        } else {
                            Log.e("-->", "IS NOT CHECKED");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

this works fine, if i check/uncheck the checkboxes.
but i have got another code, which checks all checkboxes at once, after pressing a button.

```
SelectCheckBox.setChecked(true);
```

but than the CheckedChangeListener will not be active.

Here my Code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_CheckAll:
                for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                SelectCheckBox.setChecked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your checkbox is probably already checked when you call SelectCheckBox.setChecked(true). You are using onCheckedCHANGE listener, so it gets called when checkbox changes state from check to unchecked or vice-versa

Comment: no, all checkboxes are unchecked. than i press the button => all checkboxes will be checked - but no Log.e of the ChangeListener

Answer (score 0):

SelectCheckBox.performClick() insted of SelectCheckBox.setChecked(true);  should solve your issue. I think the way you are coding .setChecked(true); is forcing the checkbox to stay in checked state.
Can you post your full activity code.

Comment: performClick isn't exactly a way to solve it - he wants to set checkbox checked to true, not perform click and thus uncheck checkbox in case it was checked.

Comment: SelectCheckBox.performClick() check the checkboxes, too. but no Log.e result

Comment: full code of the button in post 1. the code of the listener is already there

Comment: What is SelectCheckBox ?

Comment: `CheckBox SelectCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SelectCheckBox);`

Comment: Then this `SelectCheckBox.setChecked = true;` is synthetically incorrect. Also, you are breaking out of your for loop the first time you're trying to setChecked to true, is it what you want? Edit: Not even sure why you put for loop there.

Comment: breaking out of my loop. why?

Comment: You use the `break;` java keyword. It breaks out of the current loop, which means your loop stops executing after first iteration.

Comment: it is only for testing. but i think it have to work also.now my question- why not :( ok, but than only on checkbox have to be checked and the change listener have to send the Log.e

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to ask. Please fix your code first so I can at least try to understand what you are trying to achieve. Also, inside your onCheckedChangeListener there's no need to check if the checkbox is checked - you can replace `if (SelectCheckBox.isChecked())` with `if (isChecked)` - isChecked is the variable provided by the method